# About using screw in air compression and air Engine

Tags: pressure, air, kinematics

I want to use screw to build compressed air engine, as following image 
[image]

As I designed, this screw rotate in a tube 
**My Question is:** How successful this idea?

Note: If this question not related to this site of stackexchange.com, please guide me to the correct one
Thanks

Comment: There is no stackexchange site for mechanical engineering, where can I post similar questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving fluids with screws is an ancient engineering solution.  However, while it works well with water, it is not as efficient at moving air to create decent vacuums, because as @Wolphram points out, it is quite easy for backpressure to drive air the 'wrong' way. In modern scroll pumps for vacuum systems the 'scroll' action is quite different from a simple screw.  An animation can be found at [Scroll Pump Animation on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3xulCRrjos).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can this scroll animation used as a pump and as a compressed air engine?

Comment: @JustMe - yes - it should be able to do that, but construction is not easy as the scroll must be tight fitting front and back. - Jon, great answer

Comment: I don't think so, because the point of the scroll pump as shown in the animation is to isolate pockets of gas and then move them from the lower pressure region while compressing the pocket to exhaust it on the high pressure side.  Try to run it backwards, and once an air pocket is isolated there is no net force to rotate the mechanism. What you want is something more like a propeller/fan.

Comment: @tom, Jon Custer, Thanks for your Good discussion, What about "Rotary vane pump" http://goo.gl/MhKpYx , Can it be used as a compressed air engine?

Comment: I am searching for a good way to make a compressed air engine by the rotating motion, not by the linear Motion as in the pistons

Comment: @JustMe - what pressure do you want?

Comment: @tom about 100 bar

Comment: @JustMe - that is a lot of pressure with serious explosive potential. I do not know of any simple rotary system that would get you to such a high pressure - unless you purchased a special pump.

Answer (score 0):

If I did not missinterpreted the drawing, there is a spiral path through wich the air can move towards the bottom of the screw. If that happens, the presure inside the container will not increase because the air wil not be concentrated at the top, but will be free to flow anywere along the screw.

Comment: Yeah, It's a spiral path, Did you mean that the compressed air will leak out without rotation of the spiral body ?

Comment: no, it will leak when you rotate it, because as it moves forward it will push part of the air into the tube and as the preassure tries to raise,  it will push part of the air down so that they rearange to keeo the preasure contanst (at the atmospheric pasure along the tube, including along the screw.